# pdf viewer for reading scientific papers

Tags: pdf

I am looking for a way to improve my productivity reading scientific papers. One big improvement would be if I would not have to jump back and forth between the written text, the references section and google to get an idea of what a referenced paper is about. My example:

- Excerpt of text from page 2:
  "Explicit solvent models arguably provide the most detailed and complete description of hydration phenomena[1]."
- Scroll all the way down to the reference section (page 24) to find:
  "[1] Levy RM, Gallicchio E. Annu Rev Phys Chem 1998;49:531–67. [PubMed: 9933909]"
- Copy the reference and paste it into google to retrieve the title:
  "Computer simulations with explicit solvent: recent progress in the thermodynamic decomposition of free energies and in modeling electrostatic effects." and the abstract
- Return to pdf, get back to the last position in the text and continue reading until the next interesting reference comes up and repeat this process

I used texpad(https://www.texpad.com/) for a while and I enjoyed how I kept track of my references/citations. In texpad, after typing the keyword for cititing, you get shown a selection of entries in your bibliography that you could add and even abstract can be shown so that you really know what you are citing. So far I haven't found a pdf viewer that has any features for easily retrieving references.

Is there anything out there that I am not aware of?

Comment: I do not feel like this kind of question suits SO. Have you tried to look for some pdf readers? I just typed in google `pdf readers` and got lots of propositions... [check this out](https://www.google.pl/search?q=pdf+readers&oq=pdf+readers&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2615j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: you are right, maybe it is not really an SO question. But more generally I am also looking for projects that try to improve pdf viewing for a specific purpose that I may contribute to.